# LibreOffice Calc: How to remove a character from multiple columns

Tags: libreoffice-calc

For some reason, when I import data from a certain unnamed source (toggl.com), some of the time columns have an apostrophe in them.

When I have this data loaded in Calc, is there a quick, easy way to remove these?

The columns look like:

```
'12:05:12
'05:05:05
'04:04:44
```

And I want:

```
12:05:12
05:05:05
04:04:44
```

I see the =REPLACE function, but I can't seem to get that to work.  Maybe I don't understand the steps.

Comment: I copied the entire affected column into gedit and then copied it back again.  The single quotes were gone after that.

Comment: Finding this question as I am parsing my toggl export !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `=right(A1,8)` and drag it down. [Right](http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#RIGHT) will always give you the `X` rightmost characters of the string and given it's consistent in this string, it will be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 10):

If your strings are of unequal length you can use the `mid()` and `len()` commands combined.

In your example the command would be:
`=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1))`

Drag it down as in the answer above.

How does it work?

`MID` returns a sub-string of a string specified as: `MID([string], [start index], [end index])`. If the `[end index]` varies, using `LEN(A1)` specifies the length of the particular string.

Answer (score 4):

The function you are looking for is the text command, [SUBSTITUTE("Text"; "SearchText"; "NewText"; Occurrence)](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#SUBSTITUTE)

Answer (score 1):

You may try *Search For* and *Replace With* (<kbd>Ctrl+h</kbd>). In other options check *Regular expressions*.

Answer (score -2):

For me it was cell formating
try using Ctrl+M